# SEGV in Map erase using key

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, erase

Facing random issues in the below code, at line 32.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    map<string, string> gquiz1;

    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("1", "40"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("2", "30"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("3", "60"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("4", "20"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("5", "50"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("6", "50"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("7", "10"));
    string value = "10";

    std::map<string,string>::iterator it;
    for (it = gquiz1.begin(); it != gquiz1.end(); it++)
    {
        cout  <<"key = "<< it->first <<" value = "<< it->second <<endl;
    }
    std::map<string,string >::iterator itr2 = gquiz1.find("4");
    if (gquiz1.end() != itr2 )
    {
        string prevValue = (*itr2).second;

        if (value != prevValue)
        {
            gquiz1.erase("4");
            gquiz1.insert(std::pair<string, string>("4", value));
        }
    }
    std::cout << "==============================" << endl;
    for (it = gquiz1.begin(); it != gquiz1.end(); it++)
    {
        cout  <<"key = "<< it->first <<" value = "<< it->second <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to delete the element using key, then making the pair with same key and insert again with updated value.

The crash is random, and backtrace is as follows.

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0 0xf3de7133 in ?? () from /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6

(gdb) bt
#0 0xf3de7133 in ?? () from /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
#1 0xf33aa0ab in std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::erase (__x=..., this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.3/bits/stl_map.h:538
```

Changed the above to this, and never observed the same for many iterations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    map<string, string> gquiz1;

    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("1", "40"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("2", "30"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("3", "60"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("4", "20"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("5", "50"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("6", "50"));
    gquiz1.insert(pair<string, string>("7", "10"));
    string value = "10";

    std::map<string,string>::iterator it;
    for (it = gquiz1.begin(); it != gquiz1.end(); it++)
    {
        cout  <<"key = "<< it->first <<" value = "<< it->second <<endl;
    }
    std::map<string,string >::iterator itr2 = gquiz1.find("4");
    if (gquiz1.end() != itr2 )
    {
        string prevValue = (*itr2).second;

        if (value != prevValue)
        {
            itr2->second = value;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "==============================" << endl;
    for (it = gquiz1.begin(); it != gquiz1.end(); it++)
    {
        cout  <<"key = "<< it->first <<" value = "<< it->second <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Although, the 2nd approach is more optimized in terms of Stack Performance, I would be happy to know what was causing the issue in the 1st approach.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `gquiz1["4"] = value`? If the key `"4"` doesn't exist, then it will be added. If it does exist then its existing data will be replaced.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, we can optimize it many ways. But only catch is, why does erase crash ? Is it something that we have an issue from the stl_map itself from the g++ v4.3 ?

Comment: I don't have access to such an old version of GCC, but when running using GCC 4.6.4 on the compiler explorer I [can't replicate the crash](https://godbolt.org/z/KezxnYx1z). Either you're not showing us a proper [mcve] which can be used to replicate the crash. Or it's bug in your specific version of GCC and its standard library implementation. Or there's something else you're not telling us (Unusual options or flags when building?) Try to upgrade to a newer version of GCC and try again.

Comment: Then it might be a problem somewhere else, leading to undefined behavior. Perhaps writing out of bounds of some allocated memory or similar. If possible try running using a memory debugger like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or similar.

Comment: Is your code multiple threading? There may be some data race or memory corruption.

Comment: No, its not a Multithreading.. But Yes, Indeed the whole system contains Multi-threading and Multi-Processing, but not this part of the snippet. Its Straight-Forward on a creating a class object of Map, filling in initially, then at some event, find the key for which the value to be changed, and change it.

If I remove the erase, its been days that we got a crash.
All I can see is erase is the main culprit, but its getting harder to find out the reason.